# Is there a way of recording/exposing when an activity is added to CiviCRM?

Tags: activity, dates

When adding a custom activity the current time is automatically shown and can be updated. Where people are adding past/ future activities, is the actual time the activtiy is submitted also recorded somewhere in CiviCRM?

Is there a way of extracting this information?

Or should I add an extra date field in the custom data- default set to know to record the submission date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation date of an activity is not, by default, stored in CiviCRM.  Depending on what you want to do, you can:

- Create a custom field like you suggested, and write an extension that fills in the value on creation.
- Create a custom field, then define a MySQL trigger to fill in the date.  This is less portable, but higher-performance.
- You can enable binary logging (aka detailed logging) as described [here](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/advanced-configuration/logging/), which will create `log_civicrm_activity`.  This is the easiest way to record the date - but doesn't give you a good way to expose this data through the UI.

Comment: Many thanks Jon,

I'll take this forward with my team.